# adb ppp over usb whitout tethering and rooting

Tags: udp, usb, adb, ppp

I'm developing a client/server app for my Android phone (server side is Java based), and what I need now is an UDP connection over USB.

I tried `adb forward`, but it give me only TCP protocol with ridiculous latency (6~800ms), so I need UDP.

I found `adb ppp` command, but I'm not able to get it working on my Linux machine (updated Debian). I tried tons of examples found looking for `adb ppp connection` like

```
adb ppp "shell:pppd nodetach noauth noipdefault /dev/tty" nodetach noauth noipdefault notty 192.168.254.2:192.168.254.1
```

no lucky.

So, how can I give UDP power to my app?? There is some possibility without Android tether and root permission both side (Android and desktop)? I'm not interested in internet, BT or WiFi solutions. Even because Android tether request me desktop root permission to keep adb working, and I need TCP forward too.

Thank for help

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem might be the USB Tethering. Go to the `Settings` then `Wireless` then `Tethering & portable hotspot.` after that turn on the `USB Tethering`. This option only shows when USB cable is plugged in your device and its connected to your notebook. Recent android versions place this option in `Settings` -> `Tethering & portable hotspot.`.